# Displaying the JSON data in different column

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have below query regarding populating the data in different columns corresponding to their label. If you observe the below plunker, I am able to display the data from JSON file, what I need to do is to move the second iteration to FEMALE column. Thanks for any help.

**[Plunker URL](https://plnkr.co/edit/qXS9YhAJCTnTQJzyXWoz?p=preview)**

**jQuery Code**

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "data.json",
  method: "GET",
});
request.done(function(data) {
  var len = data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    var name = data[i].Name,
      id = data[i].ID,
    profession = data[i].Profession;

    $(".container table tbody").append("<tr><td>Name</td><td>" + name + "    </td></tr><tr><td>ID</td><td>" + id + "</td></tr><tr><td>Profession</td><td>" + profession + "</td></tr>");
  }
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
});
```

**Expected Result**

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Male</th>
    <th>Female</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Nitesh</td>
    <td>Shilpa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>456</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Profession</td>
    <td>Manager</td>
    <td>Developer</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: do you have any way of determining who is male and who is female?

Comment: yes, in data.json, there is a label called Gender which has value male/female

Comment: thanks just saw that, taking a look at this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution.. insert it after you get your data variables.

```
var name = data[i].Name,
id = data[i].ID,
profession = data[i].Profession,
gender = data[i].Gender;

if (gender == "Male"){
    $(".container table tbody").append("<tr><td>Name</td><td>" + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>ID</td><td>" + id + "</td></tr><tr><td>Profession</td><td>" + profession + "</td></tr>"); 
} else {
    $(".container table tbody").append("<tr><td>Name</td><td></td><td>" + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>ID</td><td></td><td>" + id + "</td></tr><tr><td>Profession</td><td></td><td>" + profession + "</td></tr>"); 
}
```

Comment: thanks, at some extent, this is working fine, but it is adding extra labels of Name, Id & Professions below which should not be there

Comment: actually what I want to achieve is, I want so show Name, ID and Profession only once in different rows but in Male & Female values to corresponding to their values in the same rows

Comment: @Nitesh please provide an example of your desired result because that was not your original question

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding but I wanted the same as I have updated in the expected result in question section, please have a look

Comment: @Nitesh wouldn't it be much easier to read that table by setting your fields as the columns and then sorting the table by male/female?

Comment: yes either way it will work for me, can you please do that?

Comment: @Nitesh first thing i would do is redesign that html table so that your columns are ID, Name, Profession, Gender.. then look into sorting your JSON data and then appending each row of data to the table. i can't look into it all right now, but later i can